# Kibana - fewer logs then usual. How to find cause?

Tags: logging, kibana, elastic-stack

I would like to analyze or explain why there are fewer logs in some situations.
[image]

As you can see the logs got down for some reason. Each log entry has a tag.
Is there a way to find if some tags are missing or produce fewer logs? 
(there are over 100 tags)

Maybe to visualize or go directly on the elastic search and make something like group by?

Thanks a lot for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. What you want is a terms aggregation. If you head to *Visualize* (rather than *Discover*), pick something like a bar chart and do a terms aggregation (be sure to set the limit to 120 or something that covers all the terms and not just the default 5).